# Parcelable with inheritance in Kotlin- Base class properties not getting parcelized

Tags: android, kotlin, parcelable, android-bundle

I have a parent class in `Kotlin` like this

```
open class Parent(
var name: String,
var dose: JsonElement?,
val other: String?) {
constructor(name: String, dose: JsonElement?)
    : this(
    name = name.toLowerCase(),
    dose = dose, 
    other = null
)
}
```

And its child class like this

```
class Child(
val type: String,
name: String,
dose: JsonElement?
 ) : Parent(name, dose), Parcelable {

constructor(parcel: Parcel) : this(
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    parcel.readString() ?: "",
    Gson().fromJson(parcel.readString(), JsonElement::class.java))

override fun writeToParcel(parcel: Parcel, flags: Int) {
    parcel.writeString(type)
    parcel.writeString(name)
    parcel.writeString(Gson().toJson(dose))
}

override fun describeContents(): Int {
    return 0
}

companion object CREATOR : Parcelable.Creator<Child> {

    override fun createFromParcel(parcel: Parcel): Child {
        return Child(parcel)
    }

    override fun newArray(size: Int): Array<Child?> {
        return arrayOfNulls(size)
    }
}
}
```

My problem here is when I pass object of child class as parcelable only child class properties are propagated. All base class properties like `name` and `dose` are null after object is de-serialized.

I have cross-verified order of reading and writing and also verified that values are being written correctly at the time of serialization. Let me know if more information is needed from my side.

Comment: I guess you need to make parent class parcelable.

Comment: I have tried it, it doesn't work. Moreover we are not allowed to call super from secondary constructors in kotlin

Comment: I have tried, and its working fine on my end

Comment: The child class looks fine (and no, you don't need to make the parent parcelable). However, this `Parent` class doesn't compile, since its secondary constructor has the same parameters as the primary constructor. So I'd guess you are using a different definition of `Parent` and if you look at it you'll find it fails to initialize properties.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ah! I had simplified classes a bit, I have different parameters in primary and secondary constructor. Let me try to edit code in question

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov done

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Then I am afraid I can't help, this looks to me like it should work. Actually, it should be impossible for `name` to be `null` here, even if you somehow read a wrong parcel.

Comment: no problem @AlexeyRomanov thanks for your effort, this is some super weird thing. I actually tried to reproduce exact same thing in a separate project and it just works fine there. Even when I used same original classes, Kotlin version plugin version. I am now resorting to full `Gson` serialization and deserialization directly in `Intent` bundles.